# How to delete tablespace and table after delete datafiles?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, datafile

I deleted datafiles with asmcmd. I need to delete tablespace and tables on this tablespace. I tried:

```
drop tablespace tablespace_name including contains cascade constraints
```

getting error:

```
ORA-14405: partitioned index contains partitions in a different tablespace
```

When I tried drop table, index or partition, getting this event and do nothing.

```
optimizer stats update retry.
```

How can I drop tablespace and all tables on this tablespace easily?

Thanks.

(Oracle 11.2.0.4.0)

Answer (score 1):

According to the My Oracle Support documents, you might have hit **Bug 19579109 : DROP TABLESPACE HANG ON RECURSIVE SQL**.

Possible workaround would be to make sure that all paritions have statistics gathered before the drop table or set event 14534 before drop command as shown below.

```
alter session set events '14534 trace name context forever, level 1';
drop table <table_name>;
```

Refer to the MOS document for details.

**Reference:** Drop Tablespace Command Slow or Hanging (Doc ID 2060324.1)